# Example of progressively measurable function that is not measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega ,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ a probability space and $(\mathcal F_t)$ a filtration. Can someone provide an example of function $f:[0,T]\times \Omega \to \mathbb R$ that is progressively (i.e. $f_{[0,t]\times \Omega }:[0,t]\times \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is $\mathcal B([0,t])\otimes \mathcal F_t$ measurable for all $t<T$), but that is not $\mathcal B([0,T])\otimes \mathcal F$ measurable ?

---

The exact definition of progressively measurable is to be $\mathcal P-$measurable where $$\mathcal P=\{\Gamma \subset [0,T]\cap \Omega \mid \forall t\leq T, \Gamma \cap ([0,t]\times \Omega )\in \mathcal B([0,t]\otimes \mathcal F_t)\},$$
but I guess that it's equivalent to than $f|_{[0,t]\times \Omega }$ to be $\mathcal B([0,t])\otimes \mathcal F_t$ measurable, no ? If not, could someone provide a counter example ?

Comment: Re your first question: $f(t,\omega) := X(\omega) 1_{[T,\infty)}(t)$ for some non-measurable $X$ should do the job, no? Re your 2nd question: Yes, it's equivalent.

Comment: @saz : thank you for your answer (and sorry if it's not that obvious for me). :) Why Re ?

Comment: Re = Regarding. You are welcome.